# Lock in wso2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I ask you the following question to see if you can help me

Every day I come across the following locks, do you have any idea how to fix them?

LOG: process 11976 still waiting for ShareLock on transaction 3041474912 after 1000.041 ms
Detail: Process holding the lock: 22780. Wait queue: 11976.
Context: while updating tuple (157,8) in relation "um_user_attribute"
Statement: UPDATE UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE SET UM_ATTR_VALUE=$1 WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_ID=$2 AND UM_TENANT_ID=$3) AND UM_ATTR_NAME=$4 AND UM_PROFILE_ID=$5 AND UM_TENANT_ID=$6

LOG: process 7588 still waiting for ExclusiveLock on tuple (158,78) of relation 25217 of database 22641 after 1000.042 ms
Detail: Process holding the lock: 11118. Wait queue: 7588, 15295.
Statement: UPDATE UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE SET UM_ATTR_VALUE=$1 WHERE UM_USER_ID=(SELECT UM_ID FROM UM_USER WHERE UM_USER_ID=$2 AND UM_TENANT_ID=$3) AND UM_ATTR_NAME=$4 AND UM_PROFILE_ID=$5 AND UM_TENANT_ID=$6

thanks a lot for your time!!!

Comment: Would you be able to add some more context information?
Which version? and which actions are happening in the system (login or something else) when these locks appear?

Comment: farasat, it is happening to us constantly, when a vacuum is executed in other databases of the system we have these locks, if we execute an insert or delete in other databases it also happens to us
On the other hand we constantly have idle transactions in transaction with the following query (taking more than 30 seconds)

SELECT UM_USER_ID, UM_USER_NAME, UM_USER_PASSWORD, UM_SALT_VALUE, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE, UM_CHANGED_TIME FROM UM_USER WHERE LOWER(UM_USER_NAME)=LOWER($1) AND UM_TENANT_ID=$2

The version is 5.10
thank you very much for your help

Comment: If I can give you any kind of information, let me know, and if I don't have it, I can get it from the work team.

Comment: Regarding the blocked query in your comment, it seems you have case-insensitive-username enabled. You may create the indexes mentioned in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/14204 to avoid those locks.

Comment: thank you very much Sajith, I will look at what you sent me and then I will tell you